# What things should be released in didReceiveMemoryWarning method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, didreceivememorywarning

What I've done is to release anything from a view in this method, but my intuition told me I might do it wrong.

In most cases, what kind of resources should be killed in  `didReceiveMemoryWarning`?

Comment: Some best practices are listed here [didReceiveMemoryWarning, viewDidUnload and dealloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069978/didreceivememorywarning-viewdidunload-and-dealloc) (note that this question is pre iOS 6, which deprecated `view(Will|Did)Unload`)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can release anything here that you can easily recreate.

- Data structures that are built or serialized from the store.
- Used-entered data if you've cached it
- Data from the network if you've cached it.

A common idiom in iOS software is to use lazy initialization.

With lazy init you don't initialise ivars in the init method, you do it in the getter instead after a check on wether it already exists:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong,readonly)NSString *testData;
@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize testData=_testData;

// Override the default getter for testData
-(NSString*)testData
{
    if(nil==_testData)
        _testData=[self createSomeData];
    return _testData;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    _testData=nil;
}
```

In this situation the memory for testData is initialised on it's first use, discarded in `didReceiveMemoryWarning`, then safely re-created the next time it's required.

Comment: wouldn't it be more sane to first do `_testData=nil;` and then call the parent method via `[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];`? also doing `[_object release];` is a good idea if it is not needed anymore.

Comment: In a non-ARC environment, you'd do that as well as the lazy init & re-init.  In an ARC environment you don't need to.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `Instruments` feature to test which objects are taking more memory in your application. Then in `didReceiveMemoryWarning` delegate callback `dealloc`, `release` those objects.

Usually media files (audio, video, images) take more memory than other kind of things. So you should focus them first.

[Here is the link of tutorial about Xcode Instruments](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode)

Answer (score 1):

One example i am posting...which i have copied from somwhere... it might give you some idea..

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

    // Release anything that's not essential, such as cached data (meaning
    // instance variables, and what else...?)

    // Obviously can't access local variables such as defined in method
    // loadView, so can't release them here We can set some instance variables
    // as nil, rather than call the release method on them, if we have defined
    // setters that retain nil and release their old values (such as through use
    // of @synthesize). This can be a better approach than using the release
    // method, because this prevents a variable from pointing to random remnant
    // data.  Note in contrast, that setting a variable directly (using "=" and
    // not using the setter), would result in a memory leak.
    self.myStringB = nil;
    self.myStringD = nil;
    [myStringA release];// No setter defined - must release it this way
    [myStringC release];// No setter defined - must release it this way

    /* 3. MUST CONFIRM: NOT necessary to release outlets here - See override of
       setView instead.
    self.labelA = nil;
    self.imageViewA = nil;
    self.subViewA = nil;
     */
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
```